# Fact Table With Non-Measure Data

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

In the model below, description is a free text field that describes why a employee was absent.

Can this description field be in the fact table and considered a degenerate dimension?

The value will mostly be used in listing reports or for dashboards where word clouds are used.

[image: Model]

Comment: I agree with RADO.. Use it as a degenerate dimension in the fact table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your design is correct. There is nothing wrong with including free text as a degenerate dimension into a fact table.

Storing comments in a dimension makes sense **only** if comments are structured (i,e, if they are standardized and effectively have 1:M relations with the fact records). If they are stored as free text, and thus have 1:1 relations with the facts, then converting them into a dimension is a big mistake - you will end up with a dimension as tall as the fact table. In proper designs, dimensions are wide and short, while fact tables are narrow and tall. Tall dimensions are a problem, because they are very expensive in terms of performance.

They are also hard to use. Let's say, you are using a reporting tool such as PowerBI. If you store your free text as a degenerate dimension in a fact table, it's easy and intuitive to use - I can write something like:

```
Reason for Absence = SELECTEDVALUE( Fact[Description])
```

and the comment will be properly displayed in a report. Done.

But if you store the same comments in a dimension, well, good luck figuring out how to add them to the report.

Answer (score 1):

Page 65 of The Data Warehouse Toolkit 3rd edition says the following:

> Text Comments Dimension: Rather than treating freeform comments as textual metrics in a fact table, they should be stored outside the fact table in a separate comments dimension (or as attributes in a dimension with one row per transaction if the comments’ cardinality matches the number of unique transactions) with a corresponding foreign key in the fact table.

*Kimball, Ralph; Ross, Margy. The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling (p. 65). Wiley. Kindle Edition.*

On page 47 there is this example of a degenerate dimension:

> For example, when an invoice has multiple line items, the line item
> fact rows inherit all the descriptive dimension foreign keys of the
> invoice, and the invoice is left with no unique content. But the
> invoice number remains a valid dimension key for fact tables at the
> line item level.

*Kimball, Ralph; Ross, Margy. The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling (p. 47). Wiley. Kindle Edition.*

Comment: And that recommendation still seems to be up to date
https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/text-comment/

Answer (score -1):

No, descriptive text columns should not be included in fact tables. Instead, this column should be included in a dimension.

If you are looking to report on tags (key words) I would create a dimension for these tags and parse the description to find the appropriate tag to associate with the fact. For example, I see 2 tags from the descriptions (funeral and sick). I would create a dimension DimAbsentReason to contain these tags.

If you need to keep the actual description, then you could create a dimension (DimAbsentReason) for the description and make the appropriate association to the fact table.